# Use Swift to Delete a Single Line from a Text File

Tags: swift

I am using a text file as an XML template for a project I am working on in Xcode with Swift 3.  Depending on the type of request I am putting together from the template, sometimes certain lines are not needed.  Is there a way in Swift to delete a single line from a text file?  My searches are coming up empty.

A little more background: At runtime the contents of the file are copied into an NSString.  I do not need to modify the text file itself, just the string that is being instantiated by the file.  I have tried doing string.replacingOccurrences(of:string with "") but that is leaving gaps in the file.  This actually works, I was just hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: A lot of unanswered questions here.  Start with "what have you tried?"  "how are you reading the file?"  "are you wanting to rewrite the file, or ignore lines on input?"

Comment: @DavidBerry, you're right, my apologies.  I've added more to my question to further qualify my request.

Comment: Change your search criteria to include the white space then :)

Comment: AH!  Didn't think about that!  I'll give it a shot.  Thank you.

Comment: See `NSRegularExpression` and it's `stringByReplacingMatchesInString` method to use regular expressions instead of fixed strings.

Comment: @DavidBerry, your suggestion got me on the right track.  Not only do you need to include the white space, but also the linefeed from the previous line.  So basically `string.replacingOccurences(of: "\n      remove this", with: "")` did the trick.  Do you want to write that up so I can give you credit?  If not I will post the solution myself later today.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The real question, of course, is "it's an xml file, who cares about white space?"  :)

Comment: @DavidBerry, LOL, True!  I guess I am just OCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your search and replace criteria to include the white space.

Another alternative would be to use `NSRegularExpresssion` and `stringByReplacingMatchesInString` to also remove all surrounding white space.